# What is the difference between "minimum alignment" and "preferred alignment"?

Tags: c++, clang, memory-alignment

Recently I observed that on Clang 9.0 **alignof** and **__alignof** are returning different values for **unsigned long long** and the same has been discussed at https://reviews.llvm.org/D54814:

> Starting in Clang 8.0 and GCC 8.0, `alignof` and `__alignof` return different values in same cases. Specifically `alignof` and `_Alignof` return the minimum alignment for a type, where as `__alignof` returns the preferred alignment.

I know about type alignment but never came across "minimum alignment" and "preferred alignment".

Could somebody please help me understand what exactly these are and what is the difference? Thanks.

Comment: On some hardware platforms you can't access a "word" on non-word boundaries, which means the minimum alignment is the size of the word. But at the same time access of a word could be more efficient if it's aligned to some even bigger value, which then would be the preferred alignment.

Comment: SIMD also comes to mind.  You might have a minimal alignment that may or may not line up for SIMD for a type and then you could have a preferred alignment that would allow SIMD without a question.

Comment: @NathanOliver can you elaborate on that or provide links for further information? How is SIMD affected by this?

Comment: @Timo Genarlly SIMD instructions require the data to be aligned to the size the CPU uses for those registers.  Suppose they use 16 bytes.  A 4 byte aligned int array may or may not be aligned for those instructions but a 16 byte aligned int array would be.

Comment: @NathanOliver Getting a bit off-topic here but still. Taking your example, with the 4 byte alignment the compiler cannot generate SIMD instructions at all because it's not guaranteed that the array has a 16 byte alignment. So even if the data would end up beeing 16 byte aligned, no vectorization would happen. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: @Timo I don't believe your assumption is correct. As far as I know if the data has the correct alignment (either by chance or you use `alignas`) then as long as the operation is vectorizable and doing the optimization pass the optimizers' algorithms then it will get vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal alignment is (on a given platform) the one which won't give crashes. On x86-64 it is one byte. On [PowerPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC) or [Sparc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC) or [RISC-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC-V) it is probably 4 or 8 bytes.

The preferred alignment is the one which is usual, e.g. because of processor bus or CPU caches. On x86-64 for `unsigned long long` it probably is 8 bytes. Any less aligned access has a performance penalty.

Details are target processor and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specific (for example, see [this](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI)). Think of [cross-compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler).

The [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) of C or of C++ is not perfectly defined and not fully formalized. Look into the C++ draft [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf): it is written in English, not formalized. But see also [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/)  (it has an experimental front end for C++) and [CompCert](http://compcert.inria.fr/). Read about [undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Comment: Thanks Basile, So can I consider minimum alignment as minimum at which app wont crash, and preferred alignment as at which it runs efficiently?

Comment: I don't like your definition.  I've never seen an `allignof` value of `1` except for things with a `sizeof` 1.

Comment: @Pendyala: that is my understanding.

Comment: Floats could for example have a preferred alignment of 16 to be able to be vectorized using SIMD instructions etc.

Comment: @NathanOliver, would be grateful if you could provide precise definition. Any links or references explain these topics?

Comment: @Pendyala C++ doesn't really have a precise definition for alignment.  What it has is defined [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.align).  For more precision you need to check the documentation for your actual implementation.